# Método actualizar una imagen en Asp.net MVC y sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hola estoy creando un programa en el cual estoy haciendo métodos para crear actualizar y eliminar. Pero tengo problemas con el método actualizar ya que quiero que actualize la imagen pero no me la actualiza se queda la misma imagen que tenia anteriormente.

Este es el controlador que estoy usando y la imagen la tengo convertida en `byte` para poderla guardar en la base de datos estoy usando sql server y asp.net MVC en c#.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Empleado empleados, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                byte[] imageData = null;
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                }
                //setear la imagen a la entidad que se creara
                empleados.imagenEmpleado = imageData;
            }
            try
            {

                    // TODO: Add update logic here
                    using (BolsasContext dbmodel = new BolsasContext())
                {


                    dbmodel.Entry(empleados).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    dbmodel.SaveChanges();

                    // return View(dbmodel.Maestros.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

y asi lo mando llamar en la vista

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" style="color:white">Imagen Empleado</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" class="btn-send" required />
        </div>
```

Comment: Coloca un breakpoint en `dbmodel.SaveChanges();` y agrega la información que existe en `empleados`

Comment: Hola, Edita la pregunta e indica el Modelo `Empleado`, y tambien lo que tienes en el DbContext `BolsasContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder modificar la información en el objeto `empleados`, primero tienes que **recuperarlo** del contexto de datos, luego asignarle los **nuevos valores** y por último **guardar** los cambios.

Según tu código, supongo que el parámetro `int id`, es el id del Empleado que quieres modificar, si es así el código sería algo como esto:

```
        // TODO: Add update logic here
        using (BolsasContext dbmodel = new BolsasContext())
        {
            // RECUPERAS LA ENTIDAD DEL CONTEXTO DE DATOS
            var _empleadoUpdate = dbmodel.Empleados.Find(id);

            // AQUI LE ASIGNAS LA NUEVA IMAGEN
            _empleadoUpdate.imagenEmpleado = imageData;
            // SI HAY MAS PROPIEDADES TAMBIÉN LAS ASIGNAS

            // MARCAS COMO MODIFICADA LA ENTIDAD
            dbmodel.Entry(_empleadoUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            // GUARDAS LOS CAMBIOS
            dbmodel.SaveChanges();
        }
```